# Missing class in Maven project using Exchange web services

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I've installed the following maven module to my local maven repository
[EWS Maven Module](https://github.com/buckett/ews-java) but the IDE (Eclipse in this case) doesn't seem to know about the following class `GetUserAvailabilityRequest.

Interestingly, I can run a `mvn compile` on my project that uses the dependency above successfully.

I can even see the class file in the jar file under my Maven Dependencies in Eclipse.

Does anyone know why this might be occurring ?

**Edit @tolitius:**

ews-java is a dependency for my project, not the project I'm trying to import

Here is the pom file in question:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.conf</groupId>
    <artifactId>conferenceclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>microsoft.exchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>exchange-ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: do you use Eclipse Maven plugin?

Comment: I use the m2eclipse plugin for Maven

Comment: what exactly is Eclipse complaining about? Can you try to reimport it as new Maven project? In the other news => `m2eclipse` is a horrible piece of software. I would switch IDE to IntelliJ instead that has a brilliant Maven support. Or drop Maven for Gradle.

Comment: Eclipse says it cannot resolve 'GetUserAvailabilityRequest' to a type, also, it doesn't show up in the Content Assist, but what is weird is that it lists 'GetUserAvailabilityRequest' when I use Open Type (Ctrl+Shift+T) as one of the available types.   I started over and here are steps I followed.  a) git clone https://github.com/buckett/ews-java b) cd ews-java c) mvn clean install d) created a new maven project in Eclipse e) Added dependency with the following coordinates groupId:microsoft.exchange,artifactId:exchange-ws-api,version:1.1.4-SNAPSHOT f)attempt to use GetUserAvailabilityRequest

Comment: I've tried switching to IntelliJ in the past but haven't been as productive as I wanted to be because I haven't used it enough. I will try to test drive Gradle for one of my side projects in the future.

Comment: is "ews-java" a dependency for your project? or is it _the_ project you are importing? post your "pom.xml" for the project your are working on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4477/discussion-between-tolitius-and-phanindra)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the class in question is not public. It had nothing to do with Maven or Eclipse or anything.I wasn't looking at the class since I didn't have the source attachment.